# Using Console.ReadLine() with a preselection

Tags: c#, console-application

I was asking myself, is it possible to use `Console.ReadLine()`(or some other statement) to display a preselection ?

Something like this:

```
Console.Write("Is that the right word(, if not correct it) ?!: "+Console.Read(word /*preselection */));
//So that the user can use the arrow keys to navigate and correct the word
```

Thanks !

Comment: How about using Console.ReadKey instead? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx